# King's Gambit Variation

Tags: opening, kings-gambit

(C32 King's Gambit Declined, Falkbeer, 5.de) 1. e4 e5 2. f4 d5 3. exd5 ...

Instead I made the move **3. fxe5**

What can this variation can be named as?

```
 [Fen ""]
 [Event "Let's Play!"]
 [Site " Chess.com"]
 [Date "Jul 1, 2016"]
 [White "anandsadasivam"]
 [Black "MaximusXIV"]
 [Result "1-0"]
 [WhiteElo "1168"]
 [BlackElo "1000"]
 [TimeControl "1 in 14 days"]
 [Termination "anandsadasivam won on time"]
 1. e4 e5 2. f4 d5 3. fxe5  1-0
```

Wherein the one with ECO code C32 comes up like this

```
[Fen ""]
1. e4 e5 2. f4 d5 3. exd5 e4 4. d3 Nf6 5. dxe4
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`1. e4 e5 2. f4 d5` is known as the **Falkbeer Countergambit**.

However, 3.fxe5?? is not a variation but a blunder. As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King's_Gambit,_Falkbeer_Countergambit) explains, you will either lose material after  3...Qh4+, 4.g3 Qxe4+ (due to a fork between the King and the Rook), or expose your King to the black pieces after 3...Qh4+,  4.Ke2 Qxe4+ 5.Kf2 Bc5+.

I am not aware of a name for 1. e4 e5 2. f4 d5 3. exd5 e4 4. d3 Nf6 5. dxe4. Not every opening variation has a name.

Comment: I'd call the latter the Falkbeer Countergambit. It becomes a Falkbeer with 3...e4 and of course it is still a Falkbeer after the common continuation 4.d3 Nf6 5. dxe4

Comment: @bof I know it's the Falkbeer Countergambit; the Wikipedia link pointed to it. But I think the OP's question was about the name of variations *within* the Falkbeer Countergambit.

Comment: How about "Main Line"?

Comment: @bof 3.fxe5?? can hardly be called the main line. "Unusual sideline" or even "Blunder line" would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Scounged As in my first comment, I was still referring to the line 4.d3 Nf6 5.dxe4 which the OP also asked about, not to 3.fxe5??

Comment: @bof Ah ok, my bad. In that case I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

The opening trap doesn't have a name, but was made famous in the game **Rigaud vs. Cooper, 1974**. Not all motifs and variations have names, but you can make reference to this famous game to name the trap.

Answer (score 1):

As already said, 3. fxe5 ?? is a terrible blunder after which the computer's evaluation drops from about equal to -5 (in Black's favor).
The correct reply by Black is to play Qh4+:

```
    [FEN "rnbqkbnr/ppp2ppp/8/3pP3/4P3/8/PPPP2PP/RNBQKBNR b KQkq - 0 3"]

    3... Qh4+ 4. g3 Qxe4+ 5. Qe2 Qxh1
```

The correct play is 3. exd5 by White, after which, Black has the choice to play the "true" counter gambit, probably unsound, but tricky:

```
    [FEN "rnbqkbnr/ppp2ppp/8/3pp3/4PP2/8/PPPP2PP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 3"]

    3. dxe5 e4 4. d3 Nf6
```

And White can claim a small advantage here.
A safer option for Black is to capture on f4, and you get a balanced game, not really a gambit anymore though !

```
    [FEN "rnbqkbnr/ppp2ppp/8/3pp3/4PP2/8/PPPP2PP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 3"]


    3. dxe5 exf4
```

With a very safe position.

Check [this article about the King's gambit](https://pawnbreak.com/getting-started-with-the-kings-gambit/) for more details about this particular trap, and about the King's gambit in general.